# Numerical test for unique continuation principle

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, analytic-continuation

Is there any numerical algorithm to test the unique continuation principle for the elliptic or parabolic equations?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "two solutions that are identical to all orders at some point are identical everywhere" --- does not seem like the type of statement that one would want to test numerically...